# Bundling of bundled products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to create a bundled product such that the options of the second part are themselves bundles of simple products:

1. Choose one of the following 2 options:

   - Simple product A
   - Simple product AA
2. Choose one of the following 3 options:

   - Simple product B AND Simple product BB
   - Simple product C AND Simple product CC
   - Simple product D AND Simple product DD

Part 1 is no problem, obviously.  But part 2...how do I require that the shopper choose both A and AA or B and BB or C and CC.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I should have added that products B, BB, C, CC, D, and DD are all sold as separate products also.  So I'd rather not just create a simple product that says B and BB because then the client has to remember to update prices in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to do this natively.  The easiest and "correct" way of doing this would be to create a simple product for each option, which you said you don't want to do.  Does the client track inventory with Magento?  Do they need to track SKUs in and out, etc? Also, is the price dynamic based on the selections or is it a set bundle price?  You could explore options with custom options, but that would be a kind of sloppy way of doing it I think. Is this something they need to use on lots of products (need to be able to repeat the process of setup)?